# The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe in UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, iframe

I am trying to load google maps on UIWebview and calling http://maps.google.com/?saddr=22.718019,75.884460&daddr=33.391823,-111.961731&zoom=10&output=embed but it is showing error "The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iFrame in UIWebview" It was working before now it is not working.I am trying to load this URL in iframe like this

```
NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&zoom=10",[self.startLat floatValue], [self.startLon floatValue], [self.destLat floatValue],[self.destLon floatValue]];       
        NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"250\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" ,googleMapsURLString];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML];
```

but it is not working and giving some WebKitError.

Please Help..
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of iFrame worked for me. Here is my method:

```
-(void)showMapOnWebview:(UIWebView*)webview withUrl:(NSString*)urlAddress
{

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><title>.</title><style>body,html,iframe{margin:0;padding:0;}</style></head><body><iframe width=\"%f\" height=\"%f\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>" ,webview.frame.size.width,webview.frame.size.height, url];

    [webview loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:url];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Google stopped calls with this parameter "output=embed" from working I think In April 2014. See https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=642868 for a workaround using the IFRAME method.

Steve

Comment: Please include the main parts of answer here and use link as a reference.